# Is Shared work in a queue in WebForms .net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Let's consider that we have a `Class Foo` and it has a `Public Shared Bar As Integer`.

Let's consider further that at the start of a given request some `Integer` value is given to `Foo.Bar`. As far as I know, requests are handled in a request queue, so while a request is being executed, the next is waiting, therefore if Request1 starts with

```
Foo.Bar = 5
```

and ends with

```
Foo.Bar = 6
```

then the next request will start with a `Foo.Bar` value of 6. Is this true, or am I misunderstanding the concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope there can be multiple requests executed at same time on server, depends on server configuration & CPU Core. so there will be multiple threads running at same time by which can be executed by different core. you can check below for default configuration - https://serverfault.com/questions/271124/what-is-the-default-number-of-concurrent-requests-that-can-be-processed-by-iis-7

Comment: So, to confirm, depending on the configuration, there can be more concurrent requests and therefore a request reaching a shared value can reach a value which exists only inside the life-cycle of another request?